# How to tell if new location is forcing file download?

Tags: javascript

I am redirecting user using `window.location.href` to a page that forces a file download using the following headers:

```
Content-Description: File Transfer
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="foo"
```

As a result, user is not taken to the page, though asked if he wishes to proceed downloading the file.

How do I tell when the response from the server is received?

The user flow that I am trying to achieve:

1. Display loader.
2. "redirect" the user (with `window.location.href`).
3. Hide loader when response is received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- From your client side code, also pass an generated ID to the server, asking it to set a cookie for you to that value.
- Your server side code should pass the cookie back with the downloaded file (in the HTTP headers).
- Then you can poll for the cookie in your javascript after the redirect to see when the server has responded with a successful connection.

Comment: +1, that's the correct flow. Unfortunately if you do not have control over the remote server you cannot achieve that.